Getting error with trainer function in colab
I am getting this error in colab, can you please help me fix this,
1906              f"Using the Trainer with PyTorch requires accelerate>={ACCELERATE_MIN_VERSION}: "
1907                     "Please run pip install transformers[torch] or pip install accelerate -U"
ImportError: Using the Trainer with PyTorch requires accelerate>=0.21.0: Please run pip install transformers[torch] or pip install accelerate -U

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below." I tried running pip install transformers[torch] or pip install accelerate -U, but it doesn't work...Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Shabnam
I tried finetuning hugging face model using my dataset...Getting errors while doing so

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
